# Text being placed over image in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm pretty new with Bootstrap and have stumbled upon an issue:

Here's the HTML of my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Watch The Shawshank Redemption</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.1/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                        <img class="img-rounded img-border" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BODU4MjU4NjIwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU2MjEyMDE@._V1_SX214_.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
                        <h2 class="pagination-centered">The Shawshank Redemption</h2>
                        <p>Two imprisoned men bond over a number of years, finding solace and eventual redemption through acts of common decency.</p>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>142 minutes</div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">Release year: 1994</div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">Category: Crime</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.1/video.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/initializers/initializer.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

However for some reason the text is being placed partly on the image as shown in the image below:

[image]

Why is the text being placed over the image? 
I thought I gave the image 3 columns and the text 9 columns of the row so I don't see how they get into each other.

Comment: Give the image a class of `img-responsive`. I think it's just that the image is too wide.

Comment: No worries! :) I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the image a class of `img-responsive`. It's just a case of the image being too wide.